# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-explanation, power-series

I need to find the sum of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)}$$
I calculate that it uniform convergence between $[-1,1]$ and .
I also know the power series of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\arctan(x)$, which seems really familiar, but I didn't have success using them.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: **Hint** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)}=x \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{n(2n-1)}$ Differentiate the $\sum$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)}\tag 1$$
for $|x|\leqslant 1$. Taking derivative:

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} \\
&= 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \\
&= 2\arctan x \\
\end{align}$$
and then integrating again:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^x \!\!f'(t)\, dt &= 2\int_0^x \!\!\arctan t\,dt \\
&= 2\left(t \arctan t -\frac12 \ln(1+t^2)\right)_{t=0}^{t=x} \tag2\\
&= f(x) - f(0) = f(x)
\end{align}$$
where the integral of $\arctan$ can be obtained by partial integration of $1\cdot\arctan x$, and $f(0) = 0$ is obvious.  Putting values in $(2)$ finally yields:

$$f(x) = 2x \arctan x -\ln(1+x^2)$$

---

### A different approach

Using partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac1{n(2n-1)} =  \frac{2}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$$
to split $f$ into two power series:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n(2n-1)} \\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{(2n-1)} 
- \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{n}}_{\textstyle=\ln(1+x^2)} \\
&= 2x\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)}}_{\textstyle\arctan x} 
- \ln(1+x^2) \\
\end{align}$$
Splitting the series might change radii of convergence, though.  Or whether it converges at $|x|=R$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!